# Uploading C# File in Web Server

Tags: c#, file-upload, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to upload my code written in C# to a web server.  Is it okay to upload `.cs file` or some other files is necessary.

Which part of the folder contains all the code so that while executing the same the one file is all enough.

Comment: You are trying to deploy a website?

Comment: No I'm trying to upload simple codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would upload the whole project file if it's for an assignment.

Right click on project(in the solution explorer window pane) and click open in explorer. Then send whole thing as a zip.

This will have the code and not just compiled files as I assume they will want to see your code.

Comment: Is it necessary or it will be okay to send the `.cs file` because I deleted all the files related to my project and kept only the `.cs file` and I'm able to open and view the code

Comment: If you have only done work on the one .cs file you could just upload that and it should be ok. Check the assignment specs, they usually specify what's required to be uploaded exactly.

Answer (score 0):

The files you need to deploy to web server are required dlls and  site content (web pages, style sheets, JavaScript files, etc).

You could use the visual studio "publish" function to deploy to a web server, which simplifies the process. 
Check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y1404zt.aspx) for step by step tutorial

Comment: I'm beginner in C# and  I'm uploading simple line of codes which of basic programs

Comment: Its like an assignment which has to be evaluated

Comment: You need to post code and desired result. I don't know if I understand what you are trying to do. Simply uploading source code to a web server don't produce any result, that code will never run, just will be text to the server. You publish web sites or web applications to web servers, unless you just want other people to see your source code